# ILO 5 Service Port Not Connecting on PC

Tags: server, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to setup a HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen10 Server. The monitor I'm using goes black after early initialization, after saying 'Switching console output to Primary Video. Please wait...'. To resolve it, I tried to connect to the PC with a USB to Ethernet adapter but when it's connected, the IP address returns wampserver.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an supported Ethernet to Ethernet Adapter?
Upon connecting you will be able to connect using the default IP 169.254.1.2
Type the same IP in your PC browser and try to login